# Xamarin issue, property isn't changed if you change it to the same property it was before

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to figure out why this works, and why what I tried did not. I have a ListView which is using the Recycle caching strategy. We have a setting that a user can toggle to make it dark or light theme. So when on dark theme, and you click one of the cells it has this highlight feature that changes the cell's background color to gray. This must be some default behavior, yet Xamarin provides no way to disable this. Anywho, to get around this, in my ViewCell logic, I set up a delegate to change the background color to black (if it's dark theme) or white (if it's light theme).

As such:

```cs
this.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
};
```

And this works.... The first time. The first time you click on a cell, it will correctly change the background color to black or white, thus overriding the highlight feature xamarin provides by default (but no way to turn it off). However, if I go back to the same grid, and click on the same cell. It didn't change the background color! Shocked, I put a breakpoint in the delegate, and fair enough, it was getting hit but not executing.

Completely confused on what this means, I fortunately decided to do a simple test:

```cs
int x = 1;
//make sure to not have a highlight affect when tapping on a cell.
this.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    //this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
    if (x == 1) {
        this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
        x++;
    } else
        this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Blue : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
};
```

Which essentially just does black/white the first time, and blue/white any time after that. And voila! It worked. The first time it went black, second it went blue. After realizing this, I simply changed my code to this:

```cs
this.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
    this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
};
```

And this works. So it's basically not actually changing the property if it's the same value as before? Very weird, but would want to get some clarification on why this is occurring? Is this a Xamarin bug?

Comment: this is a pretty common pattern, that if you set a property to it's existing value it will not update the value or fire a PropertyChanged event

Comment: While I understand why that is, the property is getting changed to gray by Xamarin. I believe if Xamarin gives you default behavior with no way to turn it off, then when I set a property to get around that, it should reflect the change. But oh well, guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the misunderstanding is to be found in your comment

> While I understand why that is, the property is getting changed to gray by Xamarin.

The `BackgroundColor` property isn't changed or modified on Tap by the Xamarin.Forms platform at all. The visual representation is changed, but not the property. The question that remains is why the defined background color (black or white) isn't used on tapping. With the information provided, I have no idea if this is an issue in your code or in XF. You should probably file a bug with a minimal repro case.

Comment: You're right. I know the "background color" isn't changing, it's something XF is doing on their own. Which is my point, they provide this functionality, but no way to override. Except for setting the background color, which to your point, doesn't make sense because it's not the background color changing.